# Implementing Scheduler in free RTos

Tags: c, scheduler, freertos

I need some help. I have a project to build an alternative scheduler for freeRTos, with a different algorithm, and try to replace it in the OS.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible in normal time? (for about few months)
2. How do I recognize the code of the scheduler in the whole OS code?

Comment: If you have those questions in mind then you probably should not write a scheduler, especially for the real-time OS.

Comment: I have to back up @Vald Lazarenko - try very hard not to attempt this.  Hacking the kernel will need an extensive test phase to ensure that whatever you have done has not broken something else.  Every time your code does not work, you will have a nagging doubt about your OS hack.  FreeRTOS is already quite flexible - it can do threads or co-routines and has all the usual synchro mechanisms to control/communicate/signal between threads - what is it that you cannot build with these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that FreeRTOS is only a few thousands lines of code it is certainly possible within a few months.  If you know how to write a scheduler, of course.

However, FreeRTOS doesn't even have a real scheduler.  It maintains a list of runnable tasks, and at every scheduling point (return from interrupt or explicit yield), it takes the highest priority task from that list.

Comment: Still, the whole thing is gathered in certain place in the code? I mean, there is one place in code, which handles all that stuff of taking the tasks and allocate memory for them, that I can change into my needs? to change the algo so it won't take just highest but consider other limitations? Or those allocations of memory are scattered in many places in the OS which means we'll need to dig any piece of code to find and change the criteria for allocating memory? Thanks a lot, and sorry for the complication, it's pretty important and got me nervous a bit...

Answer (score 1):

To add more answers to question 2:

Task controls are in tasks.c, portable/port.c contains context switches.

Have a look at the [source organization](http://www.freertos.org/a00017.html) doc; a given function name gives away which file it's defined it. There really isn't too many places where they can be either. Use grep :)